Finding World War I participant who was prisoner of war in Russian Empire
My grandmother was born in a place called Yeisk Fortress in 1921, which is now located in the Krasnodar region of Russia. Her birth record is registered in the civil registry office, and in the book, her father is listed as Horvat Anton Petrov, 26 years old (born approximately in 1895). His signature is present. I have a photo of the record page.
According to family stories, this Horvat Anton was an Austro-Hungarian prisoner of war. The prisoners were placed in the village, lived with locals, and worked there. He met my great-grandmother, and my grandmother was born. During this time, prisoners of war were allowed to return to their homeland, and he left. I have a photo of him, but no other information.
My great-grandmother, Mazurina Feodora Nikolaevna, later married Sherwood Vasily, who legally adopted my grandmother after Anton’s departure.



Do you know which of his names is the family name? "Anton" and "Petrov" both sound like given names to me, and "Horvat" sounds like a family name. There are multiple men named "Anton Horvat" born 1893-1897 in records at Ancestry. One of them died in Buchenwald, but several others immigrated to the U.S.

DNA might be your best bet.
